# sorting vector from bigger to smaller values

Tags: clojure

How is it possible to sort a vector from bigger to smaller values, because this does not work

```
(sort > ([3 1 2 4]))
```

However, using `>` for map values it is working.

```
(sort > (vals {:foo 5, :bar 2, :baz 10}))
; => (10 5 2)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that parentheses are always significant in clojure, and they never "just group" arbitrary expressions. `([3 1 2 4])` calls the vector as a function without any arguments.

You want `(sort > [3 1 2 4])`

Answer (score 5):

That's because you're not passing a vector to `sort` method :)

The correct line would be:

```
(sort > [3 1 2 4])
```

`([3 1 2 4])` should give you an `ArityException` as you are trying to use vector as a function without any parameters.

Answer (score 3):

in your working example you're using `>` on the return value from calling `(vals {:foo 5, ...})`, which is a sequence. See [docs here for vals](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clj/clojure.core/vals/).

sort works on a collection (see [docs here](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clj/clojure.core/sort/)), so a vector [3 1 2 4] is valid, as is a sequence.

Your mistake is you're trying to "run" the vector by putting brackets around it (remember the first arg of any s-exp is the function call unless it's quoted to be a list).